# Cosine formula to show if an angle is obtuse or acute

Tags: trigonometry

Keeping in mind the cosine formula: $a^2 = b^2 + c^2 -2bc\cos A$, or rearranging $\displaystyle{\cos A = \frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}}$, I need to show when $A$ is acute and when it is obtuse.

Consider $a^2 < b^2 + c^2$, this implies that $0<b^2+c^2-a^2$ hence $\cos A > 0$. This means that the principal value is in the first quadrant, so that $\frac{\pi}{2} < A < 0$, i.e. $A$ is acute.

I run into some trouble when I consider the obtuse case. Clearly, the angle has now to be in the second quadrant. Consider $a^2 > b^2 + c^2$, this implies that $0 > b^2+c^2 -a^2$, i.e. $\cos A < 0$. This implies that principal value is in the fourth quadrant! Therefore, the general solution set is: $-PV + 2n\Pi$. If $A$ is PV, then  $-\frac{\pi}{2}<A<0$ or $-\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi<A<0+ 2\pi$. But this is not what I am looking for, because I need $A$ to be in the second quadrant..

I can see that $\cos A$ in second quadrant is $-1$ multiplied by that in the fourth. What am I missing here?

Comment: $\cos A<0$ means second or third quadrant

Comment: Correct... Thanks